# Subset a dplyr result

Tags: r, dplyr

Im trying to subset the result of a dplyr call. Can someone explain why this doesnt work?

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(name=c("bob","ann"),age=c(22,24),random=c(1,2))
View(df%>%filter(name=="bob")) #works fine
#Now to avoid showing the random column I tried:
View(df%>%filter(name="bob")[,c(1,2)]) #standard subset notation to remove column 3 doesnt work here
```

Comment: You can add `(...)` around your entire dplyr chain - `(df %>% filter(name=="bob"))[, c(1,2)]`

Comment: Drat, so simple.... Thanks for your help. As a side note for anyone reading this the `()` makes the expression evaluate before subsetting it

Answer (score 3):

I think if you're going to use dplyr to filter the df, you should use dplyr to select from the df. Not sure if there's any performance differences.

```
df %>%
    filter(name == "bob") %>%
    select(1,2)

df %>%
    filter(name == "bob") %>%
    select(name, age)
```

Comment: To "remove" the `random` column, just write `df %>% filter(name == "bob") %>% select(-random)`